# Error-prone code randomly started working, but then broke again upon refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm trying to install the "selectize-rails" gem. I was having a lot of trouble ( [TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757666/typeerror-selectize-is-not-a-function) ) so I gave up for a while and worked on unrelated things. Then I returned to it, and the gem was suddenly working, though none of the code I had changed was at all relevant to it. I then altered one line of code and refreshed the page to see the result, and it once again displayed the same error in the web console it had before:

```
TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function
```

After that, this is literally all I did: 1) pressed "back" in my text editor to revert the change, 2) saved the document, and 3) refreshed the page. And, the error was still there, although the *exact same code* had worked only seconds before.

Does anyone know how that's possible?

**Here's the block of code that didn't work, then suddenly started working, then stopped again:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( typeof $.fn.selectize === 'function'); // true
    console.log( $('#select-to').length === 1 ); // true

    var REGEX_EMAIL = '([a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@' + '(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)';

    $('#select-to').selectize({
      persist: false,
      maxItems: null,
      valueField: 'email',
      labelField: 'name',
      searchField: ['name', 'email'],
      options: [ 
        {email: 'brian@thirdroute.com', name: 'Brian Reavis'},
        {email: 'nikola@tesla.com', name: 'Nikola Tesla'},
        {email: 'someone@gmail.com'}
      ],
      render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
          return '<div>' +
            (item.name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' : '') +
            (item.email ? '<span class="email">' + escape(item.email) + '</span>' : '') +
          '</div>';
        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
          var label = item.name || item.email;
          var caption = item.name ? item.email : null;
          return '<div>' +
            '<span class="label">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
            (caption ? '<span class="caption">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
          '</div>';
        }
      },
      createFilter: function(input) {
        var match, regex;

        // email@address.com
        regex = new RegExp('^' + REGEX_EMAIL + '$', 'i');
        match = input.match(regex);
        if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[0]);

        // name <email@address.com>
        regex = new RegExp('^([^<]*)\<' + REGEX_EMAIL + '\>$', 'i');
        match = input.match(regex);
        if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[2]);

        return false;
      },
      create: function(input) {
        if ((new RegExp('^' + REGEX_EMAIL + '$', 'i')).test(input)) {
          return {email: input};
        }
        var match = input.match(new RegExp('^([^<]*)\<' + REGEX_EMAIL + '\>$', 'i'));
        if (match) {
          return {
            email : match[2],
            name : $.trim(match[1])
          };
        }
        alert('Invalid email address.');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**I changed this line:**

```
{email: 'someone@gmail.com'}
```

**to this:**

```
{email: '<%= link_to "home", root_path %>'}
```

and then back.

Comment: Wild guess, but could it be a turbolinks issue? Does the error occur when you directly visit the URL but not when you navigate there from links on other pages?

Comment: @NathanWallace I think you're right, it works whenever I navigate via a link. If so, is there a way around this or should I disable turbolinks?

Comment: @NathanWallace Okay now I'm really really confused... I uninstalled turbolinks, and after that the script didn't work, regardless of how I accessed the page. So I reinstalled turbolinks, but it's stuck like that now...so even if I navigate from a link, it still doesn't work, even though all I did was uninstall and reinstall turbolinks.

Comment: @NathanWallace And I just noticed that my recaptcha doesn't work when I navigate using a link, although I can't say if that was happening before. I'm also not seeing any web console errors for the recaptcha.

Comment: Crazy... when you load the page, do you see any other JavaScript errors in the console before that one?  I just copy/pasted your code into a project of mine that has `selectize-rails` and it's working fine (no turbolinks, though IDK if that's really to blame)

Comment: @NathanWallace No, there are no other JS errors. Doesn't it mean turbolinks is probably to blame if re-installing it permanently broke my selectize?

Comment: It could be, I suppose.  I tend to blame turbolinks for all my problems (too much magic!). Try putting turbolinks back then changing your `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` to `$(document).on("ready page:load", function() { ... })` (refer https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events). Does that make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference when I type in the address, but when I use a link, the web console give more "true"s and "false"s than it used to. For example, now it says "false true false false false false false true" right after the selectize error, where it used to only say "false true".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68608/discussion-between-nathan-wallace-and-user3739453).